# Tree-Structure does not inherit generics

Tags: java, generics

My goal is to create a tree-like object structure.

For this i created a class named Node (I removed the implementation because the problem still persists without it):

```
public class Node<S> {
    public Node<S> addChild(Node<S> node) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Important to know is that i want to define the generic type S only in the root node, all child nodes should automatically inherit from the root node.

Something like this:

```
new Node<String>().addChild(
    new Node<>().addChild(
        new Node<>()
    )
)
```

I restricted the addChild method to only accept Nodes with the same generic type S,
so as far as i know my child node should know that it's generic type S has to be (in this example) String. However it seems like the generic type S gets lost after instantiating a new Node, because it gives me the following Exception:

```
error: incompatible types: Node<Object> cannot be converted to Node<String>
```

Comment: Have you considered not making your node class static?  That way the node class doesn't need to be generic.

Comment: @ChengThao This doesn't change anything, the class is only defined static because its a subclass of my main class, but i will remove it from my question because it is unnecesarry

Comment: Try creating `public class Tree<S>` . Then, within that, you can manage instances of `class Node { S thing;` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `<>` requires type inference, and the argument of the first
`addChild` must be a Node, and just passing `new Node<>()` would do - infering from the return type.
But chaining to `.addChild(new Node<>())` cannot infer anything, can only provide `Node<Object>`. So: one *cannot* use `<>`.

The problem is (of course) that you want `addChild` to return the head of the list, and keep adding to the tail of the list.

Normal practice is not to create Node instances, but just use the `S` values.

```
public class Node<S> {
    private S value;
    private Node<S> next;

    public Node(S value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static <T> void print(Node<T> root) {
        if (root == null) {
            System.out.println("empty");
            return;
        }
        System.out.print(root.value);
        System.out.print(" --> ");
        print(root.next);
    }

    public static <T> Node<T> addAll(T... values) {
        Node<T> root = null;
        Node<T> previous = null;
        for (T value : values) {
            Node<T> current = new Node<>(value);
            if (root == null) {
                root = current;
            } else {
                previous.next = current;
            }
            previous = current;
        }
        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<String> root = Node.addAll("a", "b", "c", "d");
        print(root);
    }
}
```

Comparable to `Collections.addAll` or `List.of`. If you keep a `Node<S> last` field, you could indeed create something like:

```
    public void addLast(S value) {
        last.next = new Node<>(value);
    }
```

This also shows a serious problem of the class: an empty list is not a Node.
One could use `Optional<Node<S>>` or a special constant for an empty list `EMPTY` - without value.

The normal solution is to have a container:

```
public class List<S> {
    private class Node {
        ...
    }
    private Node<S> root;
    private Node<S> last;
    private int size;

    public List<S> addLast(S value) {
        Node<S> current = new Node<>(value);
        if (root == null) {
            root = current;
            last = current;
        } else {
            last.next = current;
        }
        last = current;
        ++size;
        return this;
    }

    private int size() {
        return size;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now everything fits.

```
List<String> nodes = new List<>()
    .addLast("a")
    .addLast("b")
    .addLast("c")
    .addLast("d");
```

---

***After feedback, when wanting `Node` references.***

Then discard chaining, and make Node public again.

```
    public Node<S> addLast() {
        addLast(null);
    }
    public Node<S> addLast(S value) {
        Node<S> current = new Node<>(value);
        if (root == null) {
            root = current;
            last = current;
        } else {
            last.next = current;
        }
        last = current;
        ++size;
        return last;
    }

List<String> nodes = new List<>()
Node<String> a = nodes.addLast();
Node<String> b = nodes.addLast();
var c = nodes.addLast();
var d = nodes.addLast();
```

One could use `var` for shortness.

Comment: This is a good alternative. +1

Comment: "_or a special constant for an empty list..._" - I use Null Object Pattern for these types of problems. Using Java's `Optional` is also good, but using the pattern gives you the advantage of using the null object like the real thing. It is quite versatile once you understand it well.

Comment: This is a great solution,but at the time i define my Nodes i don't have an instance of S, so i can't store them directly in the Node. With this in mind i think what i want to achieve is impossible because of type erasure as @hfontanez said earlier. But thanks for pointing me out.

Comment: @Placeblock Then you should discard chaining. I'll extend the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is something like this

```
public class Node<T> {
    
    private Node<T> child;
    private T data = null;
    
    public Node (T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
    
    public Node<T> getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void addChild(Node<T> child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "this node's data: " + data + "; has child? " + (child != null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<String> root = new Node<> ("parent");
        Node<String> child = new Node<>("child");
        root.addChild(child);
        System.out.println(root);
        System.out.println(child);
    }
}
```

If you were to execute this, it will output

```
this node's data: parent; has child? true
this node's data: child; has child? false
this node's data: 0; has child? false
this node's data: 1; has child? false
```

Notice how I can create nodes of type `String` and `Integer`. However, this class is incomplete if you want to create a tree structure. The implementation of "tree" will depend on what kind of tree you are talking about. For example, a simple binary tree will have two children at most. Other types of trees could have more children. Also, adding nodes to a tree might require balancing the tree.

Now, to your question, this answer suffices. I was able to demonstrate the use of generics to create `Node` objects of type `T`.

Comment: This doesn't help much as my goal was to only define (in your example) the generic type T once in the root node. The child nodes should automatically get the type from the method addChild() as described above

I know how to create a tree structure, i just don't know why the error occurs

Comment: @Placeblock I think you don't understand how generics work. Having `<T>` at the class level is not enough. What I showed here is how it is done. In my code example, if you were to try `child.addChild(node1);`, the code will not compile because the parameter passed to `addChild` MUST be the same type as the object being used to invoke the method; in this case, a `String`.

Comment: @Placeblock you cannot erase the type of the new object being created and expect the compiler to guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: The problem is that i don't want to store an object of type T in my Node, i need to define the generic type for other attributes like `private Command<S> command`. The compiler doesn't have to guess what i am trying to do. The compiler knows that .addChild() needs in my exmaple String as the generic type S, so it should automatically apply the type String to my Child Node.

Comment: @Placeblock "_The compiler knows that .addChild() needs in my exmaple String as the generic type S, so it should automatically apply the type String to my Child Node_" - no, it doesn't because the type has been erased from the new object. It is an anonymous object and because it can be of ANY type, the compiler assumes `Object` by the spec.

Comment: @Placeblock https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html  Look towards the very bottom of the page. You will find the following line `OrderedPair<String, Box<Integer>> p = new OrderedPair<>("primes", new Box<Integer>(...));`. Notice how when creating an anonymous `Box` the type _must_ be provided (i.e `new Box<Integer>(...)`).